# Node.js cypher and OpenSSL differ

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, aes

Nodejs Code

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var cypher = crypto.createCipher("aes192", "pass");
var out = cypher.update("TEST1","utf8", "binary");
out += cypher.final("binary");
console.log(out);
```

NODE OUTPUT:

```
´_ËT~R  dE{
```

Command  Line:

```
echo -n "TEST1" | openssl enc -aes192
```

CLI OUTPUT:

```
Salted__?
????X-N??R?*a8  P9?t%
```

What am I doing wrong?

PD: Yeah, I know those are binary outputs but still they clearly don't match.

Comment: For one, it looks like you're using a key of "pass" in node and comparing it to it being piped directly to openssl with no key. Are you sure something is actually wrong?

Comment: openssl asks for a key with that command, in which case I enter pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `-nosalt` flag to openssl.